# firebase facebook Login: auth/internal-error

Tags: facebook, firebase, authentication

I'm having issues with using the facebook login feature. 
At the moment I have yet to deploy and am testing locally on my machine.

I've followed all the steps of:

1) Adding the facebook App ID and App Secret

2) changed the OAuth redirect URI to https://study-buddy-6646a.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

However I am still getting the following error:

> {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Error getting access token from
>   FACEBOOK, OAuth2 redirect uri is:
>   [https://study-buddy-6646a.firebaseapp.com/**/auth/handler**](https://study-buddy-6646a.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler), response:
>   OAuth2TokenResponse{params:
>   error=OAuthException&error_description=Error%20validating%20client%20secret.,
>   httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE,
>   cacheDuration=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null,
>   filename=null, lastModified=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n,
>   cookieList=[]}}","errors":[{"message":"Error getting access token from
>   FACEBOOK, OAuth2 redirect uri is:
>   [https://study-buddy-6646a.firebaseapp.com//auth/handler](https://study-buddy-6646a.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler), response:
>   OAuth2TokenResponse{params:
>   error=OAuthException&error_description=Error%20validating%20client%20secret.,
>   httpMetadata: HttpMetadata{status=400, cachePolicy=NO_CACHE,
>   cacheDuration=null, cacheImmutable=false, staleWhileRevalidate=null,
>   filename=null, lastModified=null, headers=HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n,
>   cookieList=[]}}","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: “Error validating client secret” usually means you did pass the wrong app secret or didn’t pass one at all.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get any solution?